# I suddenly can't get any bed adhesion at all on my Ender 3

Tags: creality-ender-3, adhesion

I got up this morning and went to start a 13-hour print, but when it went to print the raft the PLA filament wouldn't adhere at all to the bed. It seemed to just bunch up around the nozzle. I don't think it's a leveling issue as I just leveled the bed prior to starting. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: While there are lots of possible issues here (especially leveling related if you just leveled), I've come to believe the go-to answer for anthing "suddenly" going wrong in 3D printing should probably be "wet filament". Is it possible your filament has been contaminated by moisture?

Comment: I printed with the same spool yesterday without any issues, so unlikely to be wet filament.

Comment: I've been using it a lot lately, is it possible that it's a nozzle issue?

Comment: If you've been using abrasive filament, the nozzle could be worn.  If the nozzle is clogged or at the wrong temperature, you could have an underextrusion problem.

Comment: In that case I think it's more likely that you got the leveling wrong when re-leveling. Having the nozzle too close or too far from the bed will give you adhesion problems.

Comment: Just another 2 cents, have you cleaned the build plate? Sometimes oils or excessive/old adhesives can inhibit the proper adhesion.

Comment: nevermind I resolved it

Comment: @agarza I wipe it down after leveling because for some reason the feeler gauges are oiled.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. Remember to post it as an "answer" then in 24 hours you can accept it.

Comment: what if the issue turned out to be completely unrelated to the original question? excuse me as lm new to using stack.

Comment: That would still be an answer, potentially helpful for others stumbling upon your question.

Comment: unlikely since it was more me not checking the filament feed for jams lol